# Problems with jKit Paginate (Limit by Height)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using the jkit paginate feature and I am limiting the amount of items by height and have it set to 910 pixels.

I don't have any problems when i have enough content to go over this limit and create a second page but when content is under this limit it is not showing anything.

There are no errors so I have almost nothing to go on.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Code / Commands:

```
$('#job_table_tv').jKit('paginate', { 'limit': '910',
                                      'by' : 'height',
                                      'animation': 'fade',
                                      'speed' : '1000',
                                      'container' : 'tbody'});
```

Comment: Still having this problem, has no one else come across a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old questions and unfortunately the issue does still exist in the latest jKit.  Don't know if a bug has been submitted however the workaround is to test the current content height and only execute if over your height limit.  You must use the Advanced method (JavaScript) method as the Basic method (HTML) always executes.

```
if ($('#job_table_tv tbody').height() > 910) {
        $('#job_table_tv').jKit('paginate', { 'limit': '910',
                                  'by' : 'height',
                                  'animation': 'fade',
                                  'speed' : '1000',
                                  'container' : 'tbody'});
}
```

Comment: I love you... ahahaha but yeah I still need this thanks so much I will go give it a test.

Comment: That seems to work but I forgot how I made the page auto transition lol its been some time I will figure it out thanks for the help.